# Java Illegal start type ) expected

Tags: java, syntax, menu, compiler-errors, javafx

```
package tic.tac.toe.menu;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TicTacToeMenu extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button start = new Button();
    start.setText("How to Play?");
    start.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("\n"+"The goal of tic-tac-toe is to get 3 of your pieces in a row vertically, horizontally, or diagonally ");
            System.out.println("To play this game click inside a square to put down your piece, you choose to be 'x' or 'o' at the start");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(start);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();}

public void exit(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button exit = new Button();
    exit.setText("Quit?");
    exit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        })} // this line I get the error

    StackPane root=new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(exit);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

I am new to Java and I am trying to make a menu but on line 40 I get an error that says illegal start of type and am confused what that means. I think I am doing the syntax wrong but not sure what to fix.

Comment: Honestly, SO isn't a syntax checker. And use an IDE that will tell you you're missing brackets / parens / etc.

Comment: It is the one under public void exit I marked it with a comment

Comment: @BrianRoach sure it is...just look at the answers below. Pretty efficient too - crowd sourcing eh?

Comment: @bblincoe I know ::sigh::

Answer (score 5):

Change the code from

```
})} // this line I get the error
```

to this

```
}});
```

You need 2 consecutive closing braces: the first to finish the `handle` method, the 2nd to finish the `EventHandler`

the outer close parentheses is to finish the  `setOnAction` call. And finally a semi colon to complete the statement.

Comment: I would even suggest "next-lining" the last three characters for proper indentation.

Answer (score 5):

Change your `exit.setOnAction` call as follows

```
exit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}); // NOT })}
```

Comment: I would even suggest "next-lining" the last three characters for proper indentation.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `})}` with `}});`. You have to close blocks in the inverse order you opened them.